# SQL Statement - condition within a condition?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have a table where each record contains the time, represented by 
an `hour column (int)` and a `minute column (int)`.For example:

```
**records |hours| mins**
record1 |  15 |  30
record2 |  12 |  25
```

I want to write a statement where only the records ahead of the current time will be displayed. So far, I have:

```
SELECT... 

WHERE hours >= hour(current_time)
AND
mins >= minute(current_time)
AND...
```

But this doesn't work because it needs both the hours and mins to be greater than the current hours and minutes. How do I write to that so that if the hours are the same, then the minutes are compared?

Comment: Can you change your design?  Treat datetimes like datetimes?

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

```
WHERE  hours >= hour(current_time)
OR  (hours = hour(current_time) AND mins >= minute(currentime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Where hours * 60 + mins > hours(currentTime) * 60 + minute(currentTime)
```